# How to capture keyboard input to stop an animation in opengl code.

Tags: opengl

I have some code to move a toy car from left to right.

I want to transform the code to stop its movement by the pressing of any key for example 's'....could someone help me do that...here is my code so far.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>    // Header File For The GLUT Library  
#include <GL/gl.h>    // Header File For The OpenGL32 Library 
#include <GL/glu.h>    // Header File For The GLu32 Library 
//#include <unistd.h>     // Header File For sleeping. 

/* ASCII code for the escape key. */ 
#define ESCAPE 27 

/* The number of our GLUT window */ 
int window;  

 /* rotation angle for the triangle. */  
float rtri = 0.0f; 

 /* rotation angle for the quadrilateral. */ 
float rquad = 0.0f; 

/* A general OpenGL initialization function.  Sets all of the initial parameters. */ 
// We call this right after our OpenGL window is created. 
void InitGL(int Width, int Height)         
{
 // This Will Clear The Background Color To Black 
 glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);      
 glClearDepth(1.0);                // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer 
 glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);                // The Type Of Depth Test To Do 
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);            // Enables Depth Testing 
 glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);            // Enables Smooth Color Shading 

 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
 glLoadIdentity();                // Reset The Projection Matrix 

 gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)Width/(GLfloat)Height,0.1f,100.0f);   


 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
} 

 /* The function called when our window is resized (which shouldn't happen, because       we're fullscreen) */ 
 void ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height) 
 { 
  if (Height==0)                // Prevent A Divide By Zero If The Window Is Too Small 
  Height=1; 

  glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);        // Reset The Current Viewport And Perspective    Transformation 

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
  glLoadIdentity(); 

  gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)Width/(GLfloat)Height,0.1f,100.0f); 
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
  } 

   float ballX = -0.5f; 
   float ballY = 0.0f; 
   float ballZ = 0.0f; 

    void drawBall(void) { 

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //set ball colour 
    glTranslatef(ballX,ballY,ballZ); //moving it toward the screen a bit on creation 
    //glRotatef(ballX,ballX,ballY,ballZ); 
    glutSolidSphere (0.3, 20, 20); //create ball. 
    glTranslatef(ballX+1.5,ballY,ballZ); //moving it toward the screen a bit on creation 
    glutSolidSphere (0.3, 20, 20); // 

    } 


   /* The main drawing function. */ 
      void DrawGLScene() 
       { 
          glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        // Clear The  Screen And The Depth Buffer 
          glLoadIdentity();                // Reset The View 

          glTranslatef(rtri,0.0f,-6.0f);        // Move Left 1.5 Units And Into The Screen 6.0 

          //glRotatef(rtri,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);        // Rotate The Triangle On The Y axis 
          // draw a triangle (in smooth coloring mode) 
          glBegin(GL_POLYGON);                // start drawing a polygon 
          glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);            // Set The Color To Red 
          glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);        // Top left 
          glVertex3f(0.4f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 

          glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f); 

          glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);            // Set The Color To Green 
          glVertex3f( 1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);        // Bottom Right 
          glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);            // Set The Color To Blue 
          glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);// Bottom Left     

      //glVertex3f(); 
     glEnd();                    // we're done with the polygon (smooth color interpolation) 
   drawBall(); 

   rtri+=0.005f;                    // Increase The Rotation Variable For The Triangle 
   if(rtri>2) 
    rtri=-2.0f; 
   rquad-=15.0f;                    // Decrease The Rotation Variable For The Quad 

  // swap the buffers to display, since double buffering is used. 
   glutSwapBuffers(); 
  } 

    /* The function called whenever a key is pressed. */ 
void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y)  
{ 
/* sleep to avoid thrashing this procedure */ 
// usleep(100); 

/* If escape is pressed, kill everything. */ 
if (key == ESCAPE)  
{  
/* shut down our window */ 
glutDestroyWindow(window); 

/* exit the program...normal termination. */ 
exit(0);                   
} 
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{   
 glutInit(&argc, argv);   

 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);   

  /* get a 640 x 480 window */ 
  glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);   

  /* the window starts at the upper left corner of the screen */ 
  glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);   

  /* Open a window */   
  window = glutCreateWindow("Moving Car");   

  /* Register the function to do all our OpenGL drawing. */ 
  glutDisplayFunc(&DrawGLScene);   

  /* Go fullscreen.  This is as soon as possible. */ 
  //glutFullScreen(); 

  /* Even if there are no events, redraw our gl scene. */ 
  glutIdleFunc(&DrawGLScene); 

  /* Register the function called when our window is resized. */ 
  glutReshapeFunc(&ReSizeGLScene); 

  /* Register the function called when the keyboard is pressed. */ 
  glutKeyboardFunc(&keyPressed); 

  /* Initialize our window. */ 
  InitGL(640, 480); 

  /* Start Event Processing Engine */   
  glutMainLoop();   

   return 1; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

conditionally disable the following bit of code:

```
rtri+=0.005f;                    // Increase The Rotation Variable For The Triangle 
if(rtri>2) 
 rtri=-2.0f; 
rquad-=15.0f;                    // Decrease The Rotation Variable For The Quad
```

this can be done by adding the following to the `keyPressed` function

```
if (key == S)  
{  
updateGeom = false;//stop updating
} 
if (key == D)  
{  
updateGeom = true;//start updating
}
```

and changing the above mentioned code as

```
if(updageGeom){
    rtri+=0.005f;                    // Increase The Rotation Variable For The Triangle 
    if(rtri>2) 
     rtri=-2.0f; 
    rquad-=15.0f;                    // Decrease The Rotation Variable For The Quad 
}
```

you need to add a global boolean `updateGeom` as well